# Bootstrap datepicker displaying wrong date

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to display 2015-08-06,
But 2015-08-07 is displaying.

**JS**

```
var available_Dates = ["2015-08-06"];

$('input.date-pick').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
  var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'en');
   if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), available_Dates) == -1){
      return {
        enabled : false
             };
      }
      return;
   }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="date-pick" placeholder="Jul 18, Sat" data-date-format="M d, D" type="text">
```

I have tried google and somewhere it says might be issue with "DPGlobal" in the code. but don't have any idea what to replace with.

Please provide any suggestion
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want format

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-dd-mm',
    startDate: '-3d'
})
```

Comment: i have used 'beforeShowDay' because i need to display only available dates.

Comment: you mean dont want the user to select other dates which is not in your availble date varaible?

Comment: yes, i just wanted to display selected dates only and disable other dates and when user select that date a click event run. that's all. but i tried many codes but didn't get any solution.

Comment: any how i was able to have event, and that i can manage, but the only last issue is remain that is wrong date is displaying. I have tried hard since yesterday but didn't find any luck. please provide any suggestion. thank you.

Comment: Thank you @jameshwart lopez, with your fiddle link i started testing again with all datepicker code. and i found that previously used datepicker didn't have jquery ui. and i suppose that's created problem and with this datepicker all events and my requirements are quite working. thank you once again for providing suggestion.